# algorithm about unbound knapsack problem with possible negative weights?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

I meet an unbounded knapsack problem with possible negative weights: There are `k` items, with weights `x1, x2, ..., xk` (`xi` can be positive or negative). Every item can have infinite number. The bag can store weight `W > 0`. How to store as little number as possible with exact `W` weight, if there is no solution just return `-1`.

That is

[image]

What's the algorithm to solve this problem?

Firstly, we cannot drop negative one. For example, `x_1 = 3, x_2 = -1, W = 2`. If we drop negative one, there can be no solution. However, there can be solution `n_1=1, n_2=1`.

The naive idea of dynamic programming/recursion with memorization cannot handle negative weight with infinite number.

`dp[i][w] = minimum number of items to fill weight w by using item 1, 2, ..., i`

`dp[i][w] = min(dp[i-1][w], dp[i][w - xi] + 1)`

Since `xi` can be negative and infinite number, there can be infinite state `dp[i][w]`.

Comment: I would approach this as a subset sum problem, with the change making problem thrown in, maybe with a dash of linear Diophantine for good luck. I see no resemblance to the knapsack problem.

Comment: @user3386109 Both subset sum and change making can be formulated as knapsack problems (Martell, Toth, 1990).

Comment: The problem with negative weights is determining when there is no solution, the only way I know how to do that is factoring.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, every NP-complete problem can be formulated as every other NP-complete problem. And yet we study them separately. Why bother when they're all the same problem.

Comment: @user3386109 to be clearer then, both the change-making problem and the subset sum problem *are* types of Knapsack problems.  This problem also appears to me to be a Knapsack problem.

Comment: @user3386109 Subset sum problem is a 0-1 knapsack problem, that is every number can be chosen once or zero. Even though number is negative, it can be solved by dynamic programming with pseudo-polynomial time complexity. But I don't know how to extend negative number which I can choose infinite times.

Comment: @user3386109 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 4):

You can do a breadth-first search on the graph of achievable total weights, where there exists an edge from weight *w* to weight *v* if there is an item with weight *v-w*.  Start at 0 and find the shortest path to W.

The trick is that you don't need to consider achievable weights less then -max(|x<sub>i</sub>|) or greater than W+max(|x<sub>i</sub>|).  You don't need to consider anything else, because for every sequence of item weights that adds up to W, there is an *order* in which you can perform the additions so that the intermediate sum never goes outside those bounds.

Assuming that the weights are integers, this makes the graph finite.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confusion. I'll delete my original comment. Still: Nice observation about addition order!

Comment: Clever way to look at the problem, and cue the OP to add the constraints ... where `max(|x_i|) <= 1e18` ;)

Comment: Ha, right.  The problem is np-hard, of course, and this solution is similar to the standard DP solution for knapsack, in that it relies on a limited range of weights to be practical.

Comment: Very nice insight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot understand the bound -max(|xi|)  to W + max(|xi|)   For example, items are [5, -7]  target is 1: the minimum length solution is 5 + 5 + 5 - 7 - 7 = 1 min_length = 5, in this solution I can use two -7, that is intermediate step I can get -14 < -max(|xi|)

Comment: @maplemaple You can also use the same numbers in order 5 - 7 + 5 - 7 + 5, which stays within the bounds, so the algorithm can find this solution.  For any solution there's always an order that stays within the bounds.